# problem on taylor's expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

let f be an entire function.Suppose,for each a$\in \mathbb R$, $\exists$ at least one coefficient $c_n$ in it's expansion i.e,
f(z)=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$  which is zero.

then,which of the following are correct:

(1)$f^n(0)$=0, $\forall$ n$\ge$0

(2)$f^{2n}(0)$=0, $\forall$ n$\ge$0

(3)$f^{2n+1}(0)$=0, $\forall$ n$\ge$0

(4)$\exists$ k$\gt$0 such that $f^n(0)$=0, $\forall$ n$\ge$k

answers are given to be second and fourth..but,I have no idea on how to proceed in this problem

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: @joanpemo:sorry for that,i have made the correction..

Comment: Can you translate conditions (1) - (4) into more familiar terms?  For instance, condition 1 says that f is the zero function.  What do the others say?